# Is Covering G-d's Name Considered Erasure?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names

I'm just learning to read Hebrew, and I discovered that the text I use for Kriat Sh'ma al Hamitah contains G-d's tetragrammaton, *yud kei vav kei*. I'm afraid of accidentally using the Ineffable Name. Any ideas? I was wondering if covering it with a sticker is permissible?(in a manner which the sticker can be removed without damage to the original text i.e. on a laminated card)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Ariel. [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887), and thanks for bringing your question here. Unfortunately, this site is not intended for real, practical Rabbinic advice. For _p'sak halacha_, you should consult your local Orthodox rabbi. (Around here we use the term [CYLOR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).)